# Is "community wiki" dead?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, community-wiki

Recently I've posted a question in SO about how to ask question of a specific tag (XSLT).

I know that can be argumentative or *meta*. In fact, I decided to use the **community wiki** feature, to make sure that people correctly understood the scope of my question.

After a few minutes (perhaps seconds), I received the following comments:

- community wiki is dead
- question about how to ask question are *meta*

After 2 votes for closing, I decided to remove the question directly.

What I'm asking here now:

- is community wiki dead?
- I would like a question of the kind "How to ask XSLT question" being answered by XSLT experts, so I think *meta* is not the proper place...who is going to answer this question here?
- Is my only alternative trying to use "edit wiki tag" adding a new section, hopefully someone will accept my edit?
- should I retry to post the question?

Comment: question link?...

Comment: @Chan: I deleted the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285416/how-to-ask-xslt-questions, for 10k+ only.

Comment: @mmy: the powers of 10k+ :). Thanks

Comment: Why I'm receiving down votes here? Is that so bad? Please at least provide some explanation.

Comment: @empo down-voting on meta-discussion sites is analogous to "I don't agree with your train of thought", "I don't agree with your proposal", etc. Disagreement rather than "this question sucks."

Comment: @mark I see....

Comment: Related: [Is Community Wiki still relevant?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14567/is-community-wiki-still-relevant)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Community wiki wasn't and isn't meant to be a way to ask off-topic questions, or for questions only tangentially related to the business of the site (e.g. on Stack Overflow, that business is asking and answering questions about programming, not asking and answering questions about questions about programming).

It's meant for questions that would benefit from the entire community's input such that editing privileges should be relaxed: usually questions that invite multiple variations of the same answer. It has a very narrow purpose, and for most people, community wiki on questions is restricted altogether to require moderator approval or automatic conversion by the system after receiving a number of answers (usually a good sign people are repeating earlier answers).

So while community wiki isn't dead (long live community wiki!), your usage of it is incorrect. If it's a question about the functioning, practices, or what-have-you of a site, it's definitely a question for meta. If it's just a post about how best to ask XSLT questions (i.e., you know and you want to inform others), that's what the tag wiki is for. If it's really important it gets added immediately, you could flag a moderator down.

Comment: Thanks, so "edit tag wiki" is the right way to go? What do you mean with "flag a moderator down"?

Comment: @empo yeah, tag wiki is the way to go. Moderators can approve/reject tag wikis regardless of their reputation, so if it's crucial the tag wiki be updated (like, the current tag wiki is actively harmful), you can flag an XSLT question and make your case. But otherwise, let other XSLT-tag people look over your edits and approve them.